# COMMIT_TABLE wait type

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, change-tracking

We recently upgraded hardware and database versions (SQL Server 2008R2 Enterprise to 2012 Enterprise) in our production environment.  We also make significant use of change tracking in order to merge new data into our data warehouse.

After the upgrade, we are experiencing significant commit_table wait times according to SQL Sentry.

My question is two fold:

1. Does anyone know exactly what commit_table wait types are and if they can be ignored in the grand scheme of things.  I'm not able to dig up any information on these wait types, I have a good hunch on what they do, but have found nothing concrete. I'm assuming these waits are synchronous and are affecting the time for transactions to complete, but again I haven't been able to confirm this.http://dbpedias.com/wiki/SQL_Server:COMMIT_TABLE
2. Did SQL Server 2012 change the way change tracking works or is it merely doing a better job reporting the waits?